# How to get .NET 2.0 SP2 running in wine?

Tags: windows, wine, winetricks

I just can't seem to get the .net 2.0 Framework installed using `wine` / `winetricks`.

I typed:

> winetricks

into the terminal, selected `dotnet20sp2`, and proceeded to install it.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. After accepting the license agreement, it says "Installing" for about 5 seconds, and then reports:

> Setup Error

*(Yes, that's all it says. Silly Microsoft!)*

How should I go about installing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks quite a bit like the [winetricks bug 70](http://code.google.com/p/winezeug/issues/detail?id=70). The issue reports the root cause being in a wine bug, but I didn't go in to more detail in my investigations. If this is indeed the case, you might want to add additional information there and follow the bug for new changes in the bug status.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Mono? http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: No. Mono doesn't have the WPF.

Comment: .NET 2.0 doesn't have WPF - it was introduced in .NET 3.0. Mono fully suports .NET 2.0 API.

Comment: And wine doesn't support .NET 3.0. If you need to use WPF in linux you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) to install .net 2.0 over Ubuntu. It may help you.

Comment: How do you get playonlinux to install .NET 2.0?